# Processor for scheme [C] not found - python catboost

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, catboost

Problem:
I called train_pool = `Pool(train_file, column_description=description_file)` and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/escav/PycharmProjects/crmaccess/creditscore/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    treinamento.treinar(train_file=TRAIN_FILE, descricao_file=CD_FILE)
  File "C:\Users\escav\PycharmProjects\crmaccess\creditscore\classification.py", line 13, in treinar
    train_pool = Pool(train_file, column_description=descricao_file)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py", line 271, in __init__
    self._read(data, column_description, pairs, delimiter, has_header, thread_count)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py", line 577, in _read
    self._read_pool(pool_file, column_description, pairs, delimiter[0], has_header, thread_count)
  File "_catboost.pyx", line 997, in _catboost._PoolBase._read_pool
  File "_catboost.pyx", line 1018, in _catboost._PoolBase._read_pool
_catboost.CatboostError: c:/goagent/pipelines/buildmaster/catboost.git/catboost/libs/data_util/path_with_scheme.h:49: Processor for scheme [C] not found
```

train_file:

```
0   1   5   2   0   0   0   0   0   1   6   0   0   0   0   1   3
0   1   6   5   0   0   0   0       1   3   1   3   1   0   6   1
0   1   6   5   0   0   0   0       1   3   1   3   1   0   6   1
0   1   4   2   4   4   0   0   0   2   4   0   0   0   5   4   1
0   1   4   2   0   0   0   0       1   4   0   0   0   5   4   1
```

catboost version: 0.11.2

Operating System: Windows 10